# Simple Calculator Not Working As Expected - Beginner Help (C)

Tags: c

I'm very new when it comes to this (this is the first program I've ever written) and I'm not sure if these forums are the correct place to ask this but I was wondering if someone could help solve my problem.

When I select the questionnaire option from my calculator the first question works correctly and then the program just ends. The nested switch statement doesn't run.

```
int main () {

    /** Declaring variables (multiple variables can be declared together providing they are the same data type). **/
    int selectOperation,firstValue,secondValue,questInput,userScore,nextQuestion;

    printf("\n***Welcome back, sir!***\n");

    do {
            printf("\n***Please select your desired operation by inputting the associated value***\n\n");
            printf(" [1]: Addition \n [2]: Subtraction \n [3]: Division \n [4]: Multiplication \n [5]: Questionnaire \n");

            /** Asks the user to input an integer and stores the value in the selectOperation variable. **/
            printf("\nEnter value: ");
            scanf("%d", &selectOperation);

            /** While the selectOperation variable is not equal to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 continue to run this loop. **/
            /** The loop will continue to run until the user selects an operation. **/

    } while((selectOperation != 1) && (selectOperation != 2) && (selectOperation != 3) && (selectOperation != 4) && (selectOperation != 5));

    if ((selectOperation == 1) || (selectOperation == 2) || (selectOperation == 3) || (selectOperation == 4)) {

        /** Input first value **/
        printf("\nPlease enter the first value you would like to process:\n");
        printf("\nEnter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &firstValue);

        /** Input second value **/
        printf("\nPlease enter the second value you would like to process:\n");
        printf("\nEnter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &secondValue);
}

    /** If the selectOperation variable is equal to the case value the code for that case will be ran, for 
        example if selectOperation's current value is 1 the text "You have selected addition" will print." **/

    switch(selectOperation) {

            case 1: /** Operation: Addition **/
                    printf("\nYou have selected addition! Your answer can be found below:\n\n");
                    /** Adds the stored values of the variables firstValue and secondValue and outputs the workings/result. **/
                    printf("%d + %d = %d\n",firstValue,secondValue,firstValue+secondValue);
                    break;

            case 2: /** Operation: Subtraction **/
                    printf("\nYou have selected subtraction! Your answer can be found below:\n\n");
                    /** Subtracts the value of secondValue from firstValue and outputs the workings/result. **/
                    printf("%d - %d = %d\n",firstValue,secondValue,firstValue-secondValue);
                    break;

            case 3: /** Operation: Division **/
                    printf("\nYou have selected division! Your answer can be found below:\n\n");
                    /** Divides firstValue by secondValue and outputs the workings/result. **/
                    printf("%d / %d = %d\n",firstValue,secondValue,firstValue/secondValue);
                    break;


            case 4: /** Operation: Multiplication **/
                    printf("\nYou have selected multiplication! Your answer can be found below:\n\n");
                    /** Multiplies firstValue by secondValue and outputs the workings/result. **/
                    printf("%d * %d = %d\n",firstValue,secondValue,firstValue*secondValue);
                    break;



            case 5: /** Questionnaire **/
                    printf("\nQuestion 1: What is 48 * 3?\n");
                    printf("\nEnter value: ");
                    scanf("%d", &questInput);
                    if (questInput == 144) {
                        printf("That's correct!\n");
                        userScore = userScore  + 1;
                        nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                }
                    else {
                        printf("That's incorrect!\n");
                        nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                }

                    while(nextQuestion > 0 && nextQuestion < 5) {

                        switch(nextQuestion) {

                                case 1:
                                        printf("\nQuestion 2: What is 36 / 6?\n");
                                        printf("\nEnter value: ");
                                        scanf("%d", &questInput);
                                            if (questInput == 6) {
                                                printf("That's correct!\n");
                                                userScore = userScore  + 1;
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                printf("That's incorrect!\n");
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }

                                        break;

                                case 2:
                                        printf("\nQuestion 3: What is 1526 + 49?\n");
                                        printf("\nEnter value: ");
                                        scanf("%d", &questInput);
                                            if (questInput == 1575) {
                                                printf("That's correct!\n");
                                                userScore = userScore  + 1;
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                printf("That's incorrect!\n");
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }

                                        break;

                                case 3:
                                        printf("\nQuestion 4: What is 5 * (5 + 15)?\n");
                                        printf("\nEnter value: ");
                                        scanf("%d", &questInput);
                                            if (questInput == 100) {
                                                printf("That's correct!\n");
                                                userScore = userScore  + 1;
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                printf("That's incorrect!\n");
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }

                                            break;

                                case 4:
                                        printf("\nQuestion 5: What is 30 + 21?\n");
                                        printf("\nEnter value: ");
                                        scanf("%d", &questInput);
                                            if (questInput == 51) {
                                                printf("That's correct!\n");
                                                userScore = userScore  + 1;
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                printf("That's incorrect!\n");
                                                nextQuestion = nextQuestion + 1;
                                            }

                                            break;
        }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-format your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: That is because there *is* no loop, apart from the initial input. This would be easier to see with code that is a) properly indented, and b) broken into smaller functions. BTW you are using two inintialised variables: `userScore` and `nextQuestion`.

Comment: ...ooh I see now, there is a loop buried in `case 5:` Perhaps its non-repeat is explained by the uninitialised loop control varaible `nextQuestion` which I mentioned. In C, local variables are not automatically initialiased.

Comment: I apologize for the layout of the code, I thought it was fine and easy to read. I guess this isn't how it should be structured. As I said, this was my first attempt at writing something. What exactly is the issue with the variables userScore and nextQuestion? The userScore variable is going to be used to output the users score once the five questions have been completed and the nextQuestion variable is used to move from one question to another.

Comment: I suggest `int userScore = 0, nextQuestion = 0;`

Comment: Changing the userScore and nextQuestion initial variable values to 0 stopped the program from ending after the first question but the nested switch statement still did not run and the second question wasn't printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant, change

```
int selectOperation,firstValue,secondValue,questInput,userScore,nextQuestion;
```

to

```
int selectOperation,firstValue,secondValue,questInput,userScore = 0,nextQuestion = 0;
```

The options 1 to 4 execute once and then the program exits. Option 5 asks a series of question, and then the program exits.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've already changed the variables as you suggested but questions 2, 3, 4 & 5 are still not ran (inside the while loop). What is the reason for this?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Options 1 thru 5 are not inside any while loop. I have been running your program, options 1 to 4 ask for input for one arithmetical operator. Option 5 asks a series of questions. After each of those 5 options, the program ends. But I advise one thing: *trap the divide by 0 error in option 4, when the divisor entered is `0`*.

Comment: ... I mean option 3, the division.

Comment: I mean the while(nextQuestion > 0 && nextQuestion < 5) is not ran and the remaining four questions are not printed. Here is a screenshot of what happens when I run the program, hopefully, this will make it clearer (http://imgur.com/a/ZQZKU). Is the program working for you?

Comment: Yes it is, but I don't know why you need a loop with `case` statements: you can just ask one question after another.

Comment: I thought I would need a loop because each case statement changes the nextQuestion variable so the statement would need to be checked from the start each time the variable changed. This is very frustrating, I'm not sure why it's working for you and not me. Have you changed anything within the code?